# Differentiable distribution function is absolutely continuous.

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, probability-distributions

Suppose $F: \mathbb{R} \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ is a non-decreasing differentiable *everywhere* function, such that $\lim_{x\to+\infty}F(x) = 1$, $\:\lim_{x\to-\infty}F(x) = 0$. Is it true that $F(x)$ is absolutely continuous?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes $F$ is AC on $\mathbb R.$ Some preliminaaries:

Thm 1: Suppose $F$ is differentiable and nondecreasing on $[a,b].$ Then

$$\int_a^b F'(t)\,dt \le F(b)-F(a).$$

Thm 2: Suppose $F$ is differentiable on $[a,b],$ and $F'\in L^1[a,b].$ Then

$$\int_a^b F'(t)\,dt=F(b)-F(a).$$

It's not too hard to see Thm. 1 follows from Fatou's Lemma. Thm. 2 is harder; you can find this in Rudin RCA in the chapter titled "Differentiation".

With $F$ as in your problem, note first that $F'\ge 0$ everywhere. Thus  for any $a<b,$ Thm. 1 implies $F'\in L^1[a,b].$ And therefore by Thm. 2, $\int_a^b F'(t)\,dt=F(b)-F(a)$ whenever $a<b.$ Since $F(\infty)=1,F(-\infty)=0,$ we see $\int_{-\infty}^\infty F'(t)\,dt = 1.$ Thus $F'\in L^1(\mathbb R).$ It follows that $F\in AC(\mathbb R )$ as desired.