# Does an increasing and bounded differentiable function have bounded derivative?

Tags: real-analysis, derivatives

Suppose that $f:\mathbb{R}\to\mathbb{R}$ is differentiable, non-decreasing and bounded. Does this mean that $f'$ is bounded?

I know for a fact that if we remove the non-decreasing assumption then the answer is no.

What happens when $f$ is non-decreasing? Any hint would be great!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No: the graph of $f$ could look like a sequence of increasingly steep but increasingly small "stairs" whose heights are a convergent series.

Comment: Oh I see. Does this also means that $f$ need not be absolutely continuous?

Comment: Hmm, I'm not sure about absolute continuity. A nondecreasing, bounded, continuous function $f$ is uniformly continuous, though: given $\epsilon$, divide the range of $f$ into finitely many intervals $I_n$ of size $\epsilon/2$, and let $\delta=\min_n \lambda(f^{-1}(I_n))$. Then for $f(x)$ to change by more than $\epsilon$, $x$ must pass completely through some $I_n$ and therefore change by at least $\delta$.

Comment: It is actually absolutely continuous https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4079652/differentiable-distribution-function-is-absolutely-continuous!